# How do I change the content view when a different tab is selected? (Android HoneyCombGallery example related)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to modify the HoneyCombGallery example code to change the displayed view when tabs are changed. In the example provided by Google, the fragments displayed are always the same when you switch tabs. Only the data displayed changes. However, what I want to do is to change the fragments and the classes displayed when tabs are changed.

Here is the code I have modified in the HoneyCombGallery example: (MainActivity.java)

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    int nTabSelected = tab.getPosition();
    switch (nTabSelected) {
    case 0:
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_fragment);
        break;
    case 1:
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        break;
    }
```

everything else is pretty much the same. (also note that, as earlier, MainActivity.onCreate calls setContentView(R.layout.main) - I have not heard that calling setContentView multiple times is not allowed. I intend to do that in each tab click anyway)

And here is the layout that is being inflated in the code (settings_fragment.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frags2">
    <fragment class="com.example.android.hcgallery.SettingsFragment"
            android:id="@+id/settings_fragment2"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/titles_size"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The "settings fragment" is my class which extends Fragment: (SettingsFragment.java)

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {
    private View v;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
            final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (v != null)
            return v;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_layout, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

The xml is very straighforward as well (settings_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/settings_layout" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingTop="10dip">

    <TextView android:text="1.0.0" android:id="@+id/tv_version2"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:textSize="15dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" android:gravity="right"  >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This seems straight forward and when the app starts the settings_fragment is visible as the 0th tab is selected by default. When we select the next tab I expect that setContentView(R.layout.main) is executed and I will see the main layout (this is the same as in the Google example: no modifications). However, what I get is this exception:

```
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:224)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1777)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at com.example.android.hcgallery.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:109)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:462)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:787)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$TabClickListener.onClick(ActionBarView.java:950)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3100)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11644)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #23: Duplicate id 0x7f09000a, tag null, or parent id 0x7f090009 with another fragment for com.example.android.hcgallery.TitlesFragment
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4095)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
12-15 16:49:28.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31485):     ... 21 more
```

The error seems to be "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment"

What does this mean? Can I not do a setContentView to change the fragments and layouts as I wish when different tabs are selected?
If this is not the right way to have different layouts for different tabs, what is the right way to do it?

I have the entire source code zipped uploaded to HoneycombGallery_Modified.zip - https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0FHtQOpOYx6YWFiMDcxYmEtOGFkMy00NWU2LTk2MzMtZWY0YzdmZWUzMDU0 (Click on "File->Download original" if you want to download the whole zip file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [Developer Docs on Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) - and look into [Performing Fragment Transactions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Transactions).

Comment: I have gone through the fragments guides.. however, why would setContentView() not work? It worked the first time around when the 0th tab was selected. Why does it fail the second time when the next tab is selected? Can we not do a setContentView on the same XML file the second time around?

Comment: The Android Docs don't seem to explicitly say that you can't call `setContentView` twice within an `Activity`. I would however refrain from doing at it would probably also make your `Activity` class blob. Then `Fragments` is a way better road to take.

Comment: OK, thanks. If I did use fragments, I run into this issue: When the tablet is rotated, these things happen: The MainActivity gets created, the tab gets selected again and Android also re-creates my Fragments. However MainActivity and the tabSelected logic also try to re-create the same fragments as they did when the ap was run for the first time. I can ensure that I not create in in MainActivity onCreate by looking at the savedInstanceState. But we will end up creating it in the onTabSelected. So upon rotation we will end up creating the fragments twice. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I finally used Fragments and fixed this issue, so marking the first person who asked me to use fragments as the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

I succeeded to achieve what you need.

My situation:  I have an action bar with multiple tabs and these tabs need different layouts to display properly. 
Also I use ActionBarSherlock for backward compatibility but I think the same principle can be done with original classes.

I have 2 kind of tab:

- Tabs to display a list with a fragment to display the content of selected items in the list (that's the typical sample of fragments)
- Tabs to display a simple webView

Here's how I did, I have a class called ActionBarActivity that initialize the tabs and contains the TabListener.

Here is my ActionBarActivity:

```
public class ActionBarActivity
        extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    /**
    * The current layoutId on the screen
    */
    private int layoutId;
    protected final int LAYOUT_LIST = R.layout.list_container;
    protected final int LAYOUT_WEBVIEW = R.layout.webview_container;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode( ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS );
        getSupportActionBar().removeAllTabs();
        // we pass the layout to use for each tab
        addTab("Tab 1", LAYOUT_LIST, ListFragment.class);
        addTab("Tab 2", LAYOUT_WEBVIEW, WebViewFragment.class);

        // in case of screen orientation
        if ( savedInstanceState != null ) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem( savedInstanceState.getInt( "tab", 0 ) );
        }
        // initial setting of the content 
        updateContentView( actionBar.getSelectedTab() );

    }

    private void addTab( String title, int contentLayoutId, Class<? extends Fragment> tabClass )
    {
        Tab t = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        t.setText( tabTitle );
        t.setTag( contentLayoutId );
        t.setTabListener( new TabListener( this, tabTitle, activity, null ) );
        getSupportActionBar().addTab( t );
    }

    // that's how I deal to replace the layout used to display the tab's content 
    protected void updateContentView( Tab t )
    {
        FragmentManager fgtManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int tabLayoutId = ( Integer ) t.getTag();

        if ( tabLayoutId == LAYOUT_WEBVIEW ) {

            Fragment details = fgtManager.findFragmentById( R.id.detail_fragment);

            if(details != null && details.isInLayout()){
                FragmentTransaction transact = fgtManager.beginTransaction();
                transact.remove( details );
                transact.commit();
                details = null;
            }
        }

        if ( this.layoutId != tabLayoutId ) {
            layoutId = tabLayoutId;
            setContentView( layoutId );
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState )
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState( outState );
        outState.putInt( "tab", getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex() );
    }

    // see APIDemos.app.FragmentTabs for more details 
    public static class TabListener
            implements ActionBar.TabListener
    {
        private SherlockFragmentActivity mActivity;

        public void onTabSelected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft )
        {
            // When we select a tab we udpate the content of the ActionBarActivity 
            ((ActionBarActivity)mActivity).updateContentView( tab );

            mFragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag( mTag );
            if ( mFragment == null ) {
                mFragment = Fragment.instantiate( mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs );
                ft.add( R.id.content_fragment, mFragment, mTag );
            } else {
                ft.attach( mFragment );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my two layouts:

layout/list_container.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:id="@+id/content_fragment"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detail_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        class="my.webview.WebViewFragment">
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

layout/webview_container.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/content_fragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

PS: this is my first contribution so I will be glad to have some critics.

PPS: I'm french so I may have forgotten some English mistakes, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you should setContentView again,it can only be set once.
Set the appropriate fragment into the fragment container using fragmentTransaction.replace()

Comment: As I mentioned in the earlier comment, on tablet rotation, the fragmentTransaction.replace will get called (as the onTabSelected will get called) and then Android will also recreate my fragments. So my fragments will end up being created twice. Can I avoid this somehow?